# Set same value to an array/list without using a for loop

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to set a same value for a specific range of an array or list without using a loop. It would look as follows:

```
int[] myArray = new int[100]; 
int lower = 20; 
int upper = 80; 
int value = 5;

myArray.Method(lower,upper,value);
```

I have tried `myArray.SetValue()` and also `myList.InsertRange()` but it only allows to set one value, not a range.

Is any C#-Method doing that task?
Could that be done without a loop?

Comment: A `for` loop seems to be the obvious choice. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Are you looking for an existing framework solution, or is it ok to create your own Extension Method?

Comment: You're gonna use a loop _somehow_, it's only a question of where you hide it.

Comment: @sloth I am just curious. It happens so often that I am substituting my for loops for methods that I did not know before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could create a temporary array in the right size and copy it into your source array

```
Array.Copy(Enumerable.Repeat(value, upper-lower+1).ToArray(), 0,
           myArray, lower, upper-lower+1);
```

but that's very inefficient (and, internally, `Enumerable.Repeat` uses a loop, too)

I don't see what's wrong with a simple `for` loop:

```
for(int i = lower; i <= upper; i++)
    myArray[i] = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You require a loop somewhere, because the hardware you work on most likely does not support this type of operation.

Here is a generic extension method that will work on all array types according to your specification:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] ints = new int[5];
        ints.UpdateRange(2, 4, 5);
        //ints has value [0,0,5,5,0]
    }
}

public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static void UpdateRange<T>(this T[] array, int lowerBound, int exclusiveUpperBound, T value)
    {
        Contract.Requires(lowerBound >= 0, "lowerBound must be a positive number");
        Contract.Requires(exclusiveUpperBound > lowerBound, "exclusiveUpperBound must be greater than lower bound");
        Contract.Requires(exclusiveUpperBound <= array.Length, "exclusiveUpperBound must be less than or equal to the size of the array");

        for (int i = lowerBound; i < exclusiveUpperBound; i++) array[i] = value;
    }
}
```